# want to pass reference between two thread in node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, queue, pass-by-reference

I am trying to implement below steps in node.js

- the order can be placed and paid using my rest-API.
- Once the order status changed to **PAID** from **PLACED**, it will be enqueued that order in **Queue** data structure.
- One separate Thread is continuously running to check whether there is order in the Queue or not.  if there is order in the queue, it will be dequeued and start to **PREPARED**, **SERVED** and **COLLECTED**. Here, there may be many order's in the **Queue** or not at all.

I am sharing my code here

//order.js

```
var Queue = require('queuejs');
var queue = new Queue();
queue.enq("hello");
const threads = require('threads');
const spawn   = threads.spawn;
const thread  = spawn(function(){});

exports.payOrder = function (req, res) {

   //after changing order status to PAID in database, I enq it in queue.
    queue.enq(id);
};
exports.processOrder = function () {
   spawn("./routes/helper.js").send();
};
exports.queue = queue;
```

//helper.js

```
const Sync = require('sync');
const order = require('./order');
const dao = require('./dao');
const config = require('./config');

 Sync(function () {
    console.log("in sync");

    while (true) {
        // I got queue size always 0(zero), even though I called pay api(meaning put order into the queue by calling api) 
        if (order.queue.size() > 0) {
            console.log("here");

            var id = order.queue.deq();
            var query = "query string";
            dao.client.execute(query, [config.orderStatus.preparing, id], {prepare: true}, function (err, result) {
                Sync.sleep(5000);
                dao.client.execute(query, [config.orderStatus.served, id], {prepare: true}, function (err, result) {
                    Sync.sleep(5000);
                    dao.client.execute(query, [config.orderStatus.collected, id], {prepare: true}, function (err, result) {
                        Sync.sleep(5000);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I have exported queue in **order.js** but it is not sharing reference with **helper** thread.

I have applied many ways to achieve above functionality but not able to implement it successfully.
Can anyone please suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share references with the `thread` module.  You can send messages only.  You can either build it without the queue, or use an out of process queue.  One option would be to just use two processes with the `kue` module.

Example:

```
var kue = require('kue')
 , queue = kue.createQueue();

queue.process('email', function(job, done){
  email(job.data.to, done);
});

function email(address, done) {
  if(!isValidEmail(address)) {
    //done('invalid to address') is possible but discouraged
    return done(new Error('invalid to address'));
  }
  // email send stuff...
  done();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Apologies, I still don't understand how to use kue module according to my requirement. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I could but you didn't even make a minimal effort to apply what I said, so it would be better if you learned how to do your own programming.